# I'm receiving a compilation error in Sass - Undefined variab;e: "$i"

Tags: css, sass

```
$b: 2
$s: 7
$d: 24

@for $i from 2 through $d
    @keyframes donut_#{$i}
        0%
            transform: scale(0%)
        100%
            transform: scale(100%)

@for $i from 2 through $d
    .donut:nth-child(#{$i})
        border: #{$b}em solid #eee
        width: #{$s}em
        height: #{$s}em
        $b: $b - 0.1
        $s: $s + 5
        animation: donut_#{$i} #{$b}s cubic-bezier(.23,.74,.74,1.2) #{$b}s 1
```

The error show for the last line animation: donut_#{$i}. I'm new to Sass. Can anyone see anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't see any error while trying your code in [Online Compiler](https://beautifytools.com/sass-compiler.php), Where are you writing this and what setup you are using, Make sure to configure syntax as `SASS`.

Comment: Thanks Sameer. I'm using VS Code with live Sass Compiler by Ritwick Dey.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind. I restarted VS code, then it compiled fine.